# Interfaces, what if not all implementations use all methods?

Tags: java, interface, implementation

I'm fairly new to programming against interfaces and am trying to get it right as a major tool for developing test driven.

Currently we have a lot of Manager classes that all implement a `CRUD` interface. However some Managers don't yet do updates and some don't do delete, some may never do so.

---

**Not implemented exception?**

Is it okay, to just

```
throw new NotImplementedException()
```

until the method gets implemented or even for all time if it never does?

(obviously with a source code comment telling the programmer "this method is not supposed to be used, as e.g. Types like 'male' 'female' do never get deleted)?

---

**Split?**

Or should I split my CRUD interface into Creatable, Readable(Searchable), Updatable and Deletable? Wouldn't that clutter my class definition?

```
PersonManager implements Creatable<Person>, Updateable<Person>, Deletable<Person>, Searchable<Person>
```

---

**Split and combine?**

Or should I combine some interfaces like all 4 into CRUD and maybe some other combinations like Read + Update?

Maybe that would also create a load of interfaces where one has to click through a big inheritence path to find out which interface implements all the desired atomic interfaces for the current situation (I need read and create, so which one just implements the two? and this can get a lot more complex quickly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, for the middle stage - it is OK to use `NotImplementedException`, until you finish implementing it.

However, **as a permanentsolution - I believe it is a bad practice** [in most cases].

Instead, I'd create an interface that contains behavior common to **all** implementing classes, and **use subinterfaces** to cluster them up for more specific behavior.

The idea is similar to java standard **[`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)**, which extends a **[`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)** - we wouldn't want to regard `Set` as `SortedSet`s and give a variable of this type a value of `HashSet`, instead we use a sub-interface, `SortedSet` for this purpose.

Comment: Important counter-example: All the modification methods on `Collection` (and its sub-interfaces) are marked as optional and are clearly documented to be allowed to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Moving that to a `MutableCollection` (or an additional `StructurallyMutableCollection`) would make the collection API a huge mess.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for your input, I don't think there is black and white here - there is a lot of grey area, but I believe your [good] example is the exception, and not the common, would you agree? I added an indication that I meant for most cases - and not always in the answer.

Comment: @JoachimSauer that's an intentional break of contract by java standard lib, not 'best practice'. Not removing unsupported methods from interfaces made the whole concept rather ambigous IMO. Now you can have classes that `implement` an interface but actually don't implement it at all.

Comment: @soulcheck: I know, it definitely not the right thing to do in all cases, but I still think that they did the right thing in this case. And that's all I wanted to show: there is no clear-cut line that *always* leads to the correct decision.

Comment: @JoachimSauer yeah, I'm a purist when it comes to semantics, especially with such a basic language concept, so never liked sun's decision to support optional operations.

Answer (score 6):

Generally you would like to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` which is a runtime exception, clearly mentioning that the requested operation is not supported.

Having loads of interfaces will lead to too many files and also if someone tries to look at them they will get confused. Java docs don't help much either in such cases.

Splitting interface makes sense if there are too many operations for one interface, and not all operations are logically binded together.

For database operation rarely its the case as you will have some basic operation which will be true for most of the scenario.

Comment: As well, most developers shouldn't be coding directly against the DAOs anyway. Instead they should use higher-level business objects that abstract the DAO access. Those that use the DAOs will become familiar with which ones support which operations. And of course you'll comment them heavily, right? :)

Comment: Those Managers aren't exactly DAO. They access the DAO layer but they also know how to setup the object before it can be persisted, i.e. checking conditions, references, creating dependencies, ... Not sure yet, if I should move those tasks into the DAO 'Providers' as we call them which currently only support basic operations like save flush, delete, etc. against hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

NotImplementedException doesn't mean that class doesn't support this action. It means it's not implemented, but it will be in the future.

From logical point of view all interface methods must be implemented, and must work well. But if you leave it, and write an application just for yourself, then you will remember about this limitation. In other hand I would be angry that some developer implemented interface and left it unimplemented. So I don't think you can leave interface method not implemented just for future development.

My suggestion is rather to modify interfaces, then use exceptions inside implemented methods.

Answer (score 0):

In frameworks that support covariance and contravariance, it can be very useful to split up interfaces and then define some composite interfaces.  For frameworks that do not offer such support, (and even sometimes on frameworks which do) it is sometimes more helpful to have an interface include methods which individual implementations may or may not support (implementations should throw an exception when unsupported actions are attempted); if one is going to do that, one should include methods or properties by which outside code can ask what actions are supported without needing to use any code that will throw an exception.

Even when using interfaces that where support for actions is optional, however, it may sometimes be helpful to define additional interfaces which guarantee that certain actions will be available.  Having interfaces which inherit other interfaces without adding new members can be a good way to do this.  If done properly, the only extra work this will require on behalf of implementations is to make sure they declare themselves as the most specific type applicable.  The situation for clients is a little more complex: if clients' needs can be adequately expressed in the type system, clients can avoid the need for run-time type-checking by demanding specific types.  On the other hand, routines that pass instances between clients may be complicated by some client's demands for more specific type than the instance-passing code itself would otherwise require.